# How to replicate vector in c?

Tags: c

In the days before c++ and vector/lists, how did they expand the size of arrays when they needed to store more data?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Vector and list aren't conceptually tied to C++. Similar structures can be implemented in C, just the syntax (and error handling) would look different. For example [LodePNG](https://lodev.org/lodepng/) implements a [dynamic array](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/lodepng.cpp) with functionality very similar to that of std::vector. A sample usage looks like:

```
uivector v = {};
uivector_push_back(&v, 1);
uivector_push_back(&v, 42);
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", v.data[i]);
uivector_cleanup(&v);
```

As can be seen the usage is somewhat verbose and the code needs to be duplicated to support different types.

[nothings/stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_ds.h) gives a simpler implementation that works with any types:

```
double *v = 0;
arrpush(v, 1.0);
arrpush(v, 42.0);
for(int i = 0; i < arrlen(v); ++i)
    printf("%g\n", v[i]);
arrfree(v);
```

It also provides hash maps, and the trick it uses for type-safe containers in C can be applied to other generic containers too.

Any of these methods can expand the underlying storage either by a call to `realloc` (see below), or by allocating new storage with `malloc` and freeing the old one with `free` -- which is equivalent to how `std::vector` grows its memory in C++.

---

A lot of C code, however, resorts to managing the memory directly with realloc:

```
void* newMem = realloc(oldMem, newSize);
if(!newMem) {
    // handle error
}
oldMem = newMem;
```

Note that `realloc` returns null in case of failure, yet the old memory is still valid. In such a situation this common (and incorrect) usage leaks memory:

```
oldMem = realloc(oldMem, newSize);
if(!oldMem) {
    // handle error
}
```

Compared to `std::vector` and the C equivalents from above, the simple `realloc` method does not provide O(1) amortized guarantee, even though `realloc` may sometimes be more efficient if it happens to avoid moving the memory around.

Comment: wow cool, so whats the c++ equivalent? e.g. malloc = new, free = delete, realloc = ?

Comment: @ybungalobill, um... `vector::clear()` is not really in any way analagous to `free`.

Comment: neither of those are correct. new invokes object construction as well as memory allocation and delete invokes object deletion as well as returning memory to the system. realloc can be use to allocate, deallocate and copy memory, however it does not construct objects in the c++ sense of the word. Also beware that malloc, free and realloc do not behave the same as new and delete. malloc can return zero for a failed allocation whereas new will throw an exception. Also free used on a null pointer it will result in dereferencing the null pointer while using delete on a null pointer will do nothing

Comment: And `newSize` generally should be a multiple of the old size, in order to get amortised O(1) time complexity for the operation of appending a single item. That is, in order to prevent frequent reallocations. So you record size and capacity separately, just like `vector` does.

Comment: It's not recommended to use realloc, because it has the same complexity and on average behaves like malloc, but clarity of code suffers.

Comment: @user394242 C++ has both `malloc`, `free` and `realloc`. They are just not used as much because of the more convenient solutions C++ has to dynamic memory.

Comment: eh.. so whats behind the vector wrapper? does it use malloc,free and realloc? and if i allocated some memory with new, would i use realloc on that memory to resize it? seems weird that theres new to allocate but still have to use a c function to resize it.

Comment: @user394242: No, you can't do this. You can't use stdlib memory functions with C++ new/delete operators. See the LodePNG implementation (it's the first ~100 lines in the cpp) to see an example of how it is done...

Comment: @Chris the C89 standard I have says, "4.10.3.2 The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  _If ptr
is a null pointer, no action occurs._"

Answer (score 35):

A lot of C projects end up implementing a vector-like API.  Dynamic arrays are such a common need, that it's nice to abstract away the memory management as much as possible.  A typical C implementation might look something like:

```
typedef struct dynamic_array_struct
{
  int* data;
  size_t capacity; /* total capacity */
  size_t size; /* number of elements in vector */
} vector;
```

Then they would have various API function calls which operate on the `vector`:

```
int vector_init(vector* v, size_t init_capacity)
{
  v->data = malloc(init_capacity * sizeof(int));
  if (!v->data) return -1;

  v->size = 0;
  v->capacity = init_capacity;

  return 0; /* success */
}
```

Then of course, you need functions for `push_back`, `insert`, `resize`, etc, which would call `realloc` if `size` exceeds `capacity`.

```
vector_resize(vector* v, size_t new_size);

vector_push_back(vector* v, int element);
```

Usually, when a reallocation is needed, `capacity` is doubled to avoid reallocating all the time.  This is usually the same strategy employed internally by `std::vector`, except typically `std::vector` won't call `realloc` because of C++ object construction/destruction.  Rather, `std::vector` might allocate a new buffer, and then copy construct/move construct the objects (using placement `new`) into the new buffer.

An actual vector implementation in C might use `void*` pointers as elements rather than `int`, so the code is more generic.  Anyway, this sort of thing is implemented in a lot of C projects.  See http://codingrecipes.com/implementation-of-a-vector-data-structure-in-c for an example vector implementation in C.

Comment: Here you seem to create a pointer for the data variable of your struct, but for a lot of other vector implementations online I saw that the data variable of the structure was held by a double pointer. What is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: Link is broken, see https://gist.github.com/EmilHernvall/953968/0fef1b1f826a8c3d8cfb74b2915f17d2944ec1d0 for what seems to be a popular implementation

Comment: @WarlikeChimpanzee Your link is broken too now.

Comment: https://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-a-dynamic-vector-array-in-c/

Answer (score 11):

They would start by hiding the defining a structure that would hold members necessary for the implementation.  Then providing a group of functions that would manipulate the contents of the structure.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct vec
{
    unsigned char* _mem;
    unsigned long _elems;
    unsigned long _elemsize;
    unsigned long _capelems;
    unsigned long _reserve;
};

vec* vec_new(unsigned long elemsize)
{
    vec* pvec = (vec*)malloc(sizeof(vec));
    pvec->_reserve = 10;
    pvec->_capelems = pvec->_reserve;
    pvec->_elemsize = elemsize;
    pvec->_elems = 0;
    pvec->_mem = (unsigned char*)malloc(pvec->_capelems * pvec->_elemsize);
    return pvec;
}

void vec_delete(vec* pvec)
{
    free(pvec->_mem);
    free(pvec);
}

void vec_grow(vec* pvec)
{
    unsigned char* mem = (unsigned char*)malloc((pvec->_capelems + pvec->_reserve) * pvec->_elemsize);
    memcpy(mem, pvec->_mem, pvec->_elems * pvec->_elemsize);
    free(pvec->_mem);
    pvec->_mem = mem;
    pvec->_capelems += pvec->_reserve;
}

void vec_push_back(vec* pvec, void* data, unsigned long elemsize)
{
    assert(elemsize == pvec->_elemsize);
    if (pvec->_elems == pvec->_capelems) {
        vec_grow(pvec);
    }
    memcpy(pvec->_mem + (pvec->_elems * pvec->_elemsize), (unsigned char*)data, pvec->_elemsize);
    pvec->_elems++;    
}

unsigned long vec_length(vec* pvec)
{
    return pvec->_elems;
}

void* vec_get(vec* pvec, unsigned long index)
{
    assert(index < pvec->_elems);
    return (void*)(pvec->_mem + (index * pvec->_elemsize));
}

void vec_copy_item(vec* pvec, void* dest, unsigned long index)
{
    memcpy(dest, vec_get(pvec, index), pvec->_elemsize);
}

void playwithvec()
{
    vec* pvec = vec_new(sizeof(int));

    for (int val = 0; val < 1000; val += 10) {
        vec_push_back(pvec, &val, sizeof(val));
    }

    for (unsigned long index = (int)vec_length(pvec) - 1; (int)index >= 0; index--) {
        int val;
        vec_copy_item(pvec, &val, index);
        printf("vec(%d) = %d\n", index, val);
    }

    vec_delete(pvec);
}
```

Further to this they would achieve encapsulation by using void* in the place of vec* for the function group, and actually hide the structure definition from the user by defining it within the C module containing the group of functions rather than the header.  Also they would hide the functions that you would consider to be private, by leaving them out from the header and simply prototyping them only in the C module.

Comment: Wrote this in 30 mins, no guarantee.

Answer (score 5):

You can see implementation [vc_vector](https://github.com/skogorev/vc_vector):

```
struct vc_vector {
  size_t count;
  size_t element_size;
  size_t reserved_size;
  char* data;
  vc_vector_deleter* deleter;
};

...

vc_vector* vc_vector_create_copy(const vc_vector* vector) {
  vc_vector* new_vector = vc_vector_create(vector->reserved_size / vector->count,
                                           vector->element_size,
                                           vector->deleter);
  if (unlikely(!new_vector)) {
    return new_vector;
  }

  if (memcpy(vector->data,
             new_vector->data,
             new_vector->element_size * vector->count) == NULL) {
    vc_vector_release(new_vector);
    new_vector = NULL;
    return new_vector;
  }

  new_vector->count = vector->count;
  return new_vector;
}
```

To use it:

```
vc_vector* v1 = vc_vector_create(0, sizeof(int), NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  vc_vector_push_back(v1, &i);
}

// v1 = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

vc_vector* v2 = vc_vector_create_copy(v1);

// v2 = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (copy of v1)

// to get pointer to int:

const int* v2_data = vc_vector_data(v1);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/jakubgorny47/baku-code/tree/master/c_vector

Here's my implementation. It's basicaly a struct containing pointer to the data, size (in elements), overall allocated space and a size of the type that's being stored in vector to allow use of void pointer.

Comment: This would be better if, as per other answers here, you included the code directly in your answer as well as the link; not least because this answer comes so far in time after the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**Gena**" library. It closely resembles `stl::vector` in pure **C89**.

From the README, it features:

- Access vector elements just like plain C arrays: `vec[k][j]`;
- Have multi-dimentional arrays;
- Copy vectors;
- Instantiate necessary vector types once in a separate module, instead of doing this every time you needed a vector;
- You can choose how to pass values into a vector and how to return them from it: by value or by pointer.

You can check it out here:

https://github.com/cher-nov/Gena