# Post Increment with respect to Sequence Points

Tags: c, post-increment, sequence-points

When does the post increment operator affect the increment? I have come across two opinions:

1) From http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_015.htm:

> POST means do the operation after any
>   assignment operation.

2) Closer home, an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept/4445841#4445841)(albeit on C++) says:

> ... that delays the increment
>   until the end of the expression 
>       (next sequence point).

So does the post increment operation...

A) wait until a sequence point is reached or

B) happen post an assignment operator or

C) happen anytime before the sequence point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct interpretation is C, ie. the increment happens sometime before the next sequence point, specifically the C standard (C99, 6.5.2.4, 2) says this:

> The side effect of updating the stored value of the operand shall occur between
>   the previous and the next sequence point.

Full paragraph quotation:

> The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. After the result is
>   obtained, the value of the operand is incremented. (That is, the value 1 of the appropriate
>   type is added to it.) See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment
>   for information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
>   pointers. The side effect of updating the stored value of the operand shall occur between
>   the previous and the next sequence point.

Comment: So, is `i = 0; a[i++] = 10;` undefined, as `i` may increment anytime before the semicolon?

Comment: @crypto: No, the value is retrieved before incrementing. I've added the complete quotation of the paragraph to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The post increment operation always occurs before the next sequence point irrespective of the expression where the increment operator is being used.
See this link for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point