# Call a function multiple times with the same input but get different return value

Tags: c, xor, crc

I'm using GNU C in Ubuntu 14.0.4. I wrote a CRC_XOR() function and call it with the same input argument multiple times. But It's wierd, each call may sometimes get different result. What's going wrong?
Sample code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char CRC_XOR(char *as_Pkt,int ai_len);
void DO_Get_CRC(void);
int main(void)
{
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 03
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 03
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 00  (strange?)  
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 03
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 00  (strange?) 
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 03
    DO_Get_CRC(); //get 01 00 02 00  (strange?) 
    exit(0);
}
/*
    use same input to invoke CRC_XOR()
*/
void DO_Get_CRC(void)
{
    char  ls_pkt[20];
    int   li_idx;
    short li_max = 512;
    int   li_len = 0;

    ls_pkt[li_len++] = 0x01;  //station ID
    ls_pkt[li_len++] = 0x00;  //length-low byte
    ls_pkt[li_len++] = 0x02;  //length-high byte
    ls_pkt[li_len++] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len);
    ls_pkt[li_len]   = 0;
    for (li_idx=0; li_idx<li_len;li_idx++) {
         printf("%02X ", ls_pkt[li_idx]); //display in hexdigits
    }

    printf("\n");
}
/*
    return 1 byte of CRC by XOR byte array
*/
char CRC_XOR(char *as_Pkt,int ai_len)
{
    int  li_idx;
    char lc_CRC = 0x00;

    for (li_idx=0; li_idx < ai_len; li_idx++){
        lc_CRC ^= as_Pkt[li_idx]; //XOR each byte
    }
    return (char)(lc_CRC & 0x000000FF); //return CRC byte
}
```

Comment: The program you should should not build. What is, for example, `li_len`? Where is it defined? What is it initialized to?

Comment: As for your problem, please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. And learn how to use a debugger, which is the right tool to solve problems like this.

Comment: Sorry, I removed li_len, it's 4 of course

Comment: Have you removed anything else that could potentially be of substance? I can't reproduce your behavior.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note: The `main` function should be declared to return an `int`. It is required by the C specification. On a more related note: Do you get any warnings when building? What if you enable more warnings (something you really should do anyway, I recommend at least adding `-Wall` when compiling)? If you get warnings, what do they say? Could they be related to your problem?

Comment: This program isn't buildable as posted.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time to ask question here. I've copied the source program. As you can see, the bug may occur in this line:   ls_pkt[li_len++] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len); if I changed li_len++ to li_len. The bug disappeared. However thank you so much for your kindness

Comment: @VictorHuang wait a second, let's make this even better. With `li_len++` in place can you compile it into assembly, with `gcc -S` and then copy the contents of the produced `.s` file, it would be nice to see the compiler output!

Comment: @VictorHuang btw your code has a portability bug. `"%02x"` should be `%02hhx` because you're printing characters, not ints...

Comment: Why are you programming this in such a complicated way? Just *initialize* your `ls_pkt` array properly and then call `CRC_XOR` for element `3`.

Comment: @JensGustedt it probably is a *MCVE*...

Answer (score 8):

You have *undefined behavior*.

The reason is because there is no sequence point with assignment.

For

```
ls_pkt[li_len++] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len);
```

you don't know if `li_len++` happens before or after the evaluation of `li_len` in the function call. That in turns might mean that `li_len` might be equal to `4` which means your `CRC_XOR` function will use the as of yet uninitialized `ls_pkt[4]`.

Since `ls_pkt[4]` is uninitialized before the assignment, its value will be *indeterminate*, and might be seemingly random.

The simple solution is to increase `li_len` *after* the assignment:

```
ls_pkt[li_len] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len);
++li_len;
```

Comment: Generally, programming with side effects is a bad idea. It buys you nothing but trouble.

Comment: I think this comes under the clause that all reads between the sequence points should directly be required for the write.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't originally reproduce in 64-bit mode in my x86, but it seems to be easy to reproduce on my computer in 32-bit mode; perhaps the different stack width is the reason.

```
% gcc crc.c -m32
% ./a.out  
01 00 02 03 
01 00 02 00 
01 00 02 03 
01 00 02 00 
01 00 02 03 
01 00 02 00 
01 00 02 03
```

I've numbered the lines here so one can easily see how they correspond to the `.loc` lines from the assembler output:

```
20  void DO_Get_CRC(void)
21  {
22      char  ls_pkt[20];
23      int   li_idx;
24      short li_max = 512;
25      int   li_len = 0;
26
27      ls_pkt[li_len++] = 0x01;  //station ID
28      ls_pkt[li_len++] = 0x00;  //length-low byte
29      ls_pkt[li_len++] = 0x02;  //length-high byte
30      ls_pkt[li_len++] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len);
31      ls_pkt[li_len]   = 0;
32      for (li_idx=0; li_idx<li_len;li_idx++) {
33           printf("%02X ", ls_pkt[li_idx]); //display in hexdigits
34      }
35
36      printf("\n");
37  }
```

Compiling this into assembly, we get the following assembler output:

```
DO_Get_CRC:
.LFB3:
        .loc 1 21 0
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        pushl   %esi
        pushl   %ebx
        subl    $48, %esp
        .cfi_offset 6, -12
        .cfi_offset 3, -16
        call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
        addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %ebx
        .loc 1 21 0
        movl    %gs:20, %eax
        movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        .loc 1 24 0
        movw    $512, -42(%ebp)
        .loc 1 25 0
        movl    $0, -36(%ebp)      // int li_len = 0
        .loc 1 27 0
        movl    -36(%ebp), %eax    // eax = li_len
        leal    1(%eax), %edx      // edx = eax + 1
        movl    %edx, -36(%ebp)    // li_len = edx
        movb    $1, -32(%ebp,%eax) // ls_pkt[eax] = 1
        .loc 1 28 0
        movl    -36(%ebp), %eax    // eax = li_len
        leal    1(%eax), %edx      // edx = eax + 1
        movl    %edx, -36(%ebp)    // li_len = edx
        movb    $0, -32(%ebp,%eax) // ls_pkt[eax] = 0
        .loc 1 29 0
        movl    -36(%ebp), %eax    // eax = li_len
        leal    1(%eax), %edx      // edx = eax + 1
        movl    %edx, -36(%ebp)    // li_len = edx
        movb    $2, -32(%ebp,%eax) // ls_pkt[eax] = 2
        .loc 1 30 0
        movl    -36(%ebp), %esi    // esi = li_len
        leal    1(%esi), %eax      // eax = esi + 1
        movl    %eax, -36(%ebp)    // li_len = eax --li_len is now **4**
        subl    $8, %esp
        pushl   -36(%ebp)          // push the value of li_len (2nd arg)
        leal    -32(%ebp), %eax    // load address of ls_pkt
        pushl   %eax               // and push ls_pkt (1śt arg)
        call    CRC_XOR            // call CRC_XOR
```

The post-increments are encoded as the "load effective address" instruction, it is a common trick in X86 assembler to use the address calculation hardware for constant arithmetic as the instructions are smaller. Anyway, there are a total of **4** `leal 1(%XXX), %YYY` followed by `movl %YYY, -36(%ebp)`, where `-36(%ebp)` is the location of the variable `li_len`, meaning that `li_len` was incremented **4** times before its value is pushed onto the stack as the *argument* for `CRC_XOR`. However if the code is mutated *elsewhere* it easily happens so that the same compiler produces code that increments `li_len` only 3 times before calling the function, proving that they're indeed indeterminately sequenced.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` in this line

```
void DO_Get_CRC(void); --> void DO_Get_CRC(void)
```

Modify this line, because you wanted to pass `li_len` but you passing `li_len+1` because of `++` while assigning

```
ls_pkt[li_len++] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len); -->  ls_pkt[li_len++] = CRC_XOR(ls_pkt,li_len-1);
```

Its works fine without any issue
main.c:31:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sh-4.2$ gcc -o main *.c
sh-4.2$ main
01 00 02 03
01 00 02 03
01 00 02 03
01 00 02 03
01 00 02 03
01 00 02 03
01 00 02 03

Comment: That misplaced semicolon should lead to build-errors, not unexpected results.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for pointing, because i missed to paste important code line change

Comment: no, that fix is *absolutely incorrect*. Please read and understand @Someprogrammerdude's answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala don't know for what you referring. But as per logic, CRC_XOR function should receive 3 but it receives 4 because of increment.

Comment: @ThiruShetty your "fix" repeats the same problem.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i have put in loop and run for 1000 times but the result is same under ubuntu 16.04, I don't know about other platforms

Comment: @ThiruShetty exactly, that is the problem. You "fixed" the problem., The corpse is under the carpet.

Comment: The thing is, it is never specified **when** `++` increments the pointer. It just needs to do so before *calling the function*, not before preparing the arguments for the function call. [More explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865599/post-increment-with-respect-to-sequence-points). Thus you cannot fix this by assuming that it was incremented *before* you calculate `i + 1`. There is no such guarantee.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151581/discussion-between-thiru-shetty-and-antti-haapala).