# Smart way to filter array in c

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I am currently programming in c and I was wondering if there's a smart way of filtering an array to make another array satisfying certain conditions.

An example problem would be:
  Given an array of random integers of size 10, generate an array containing only even numbers that were in the array.

Since it is difficult to know how many elements satisfy the condition, I am checking through the array twice, once counting the number of elements that satisfy the condition, and then actually putting the corresponding elements into the array.

One other thing I tried is making an integer array of size 10, storing all indices satisfying the conditions on the first run and then just reading off the elements in the array of the desired index when copying desired elements into the array.

In general, the array may be huge and checking conditions may be expensive, so I don't think this method would do well.

I feel like there should be smarter & more efficient ways to do this. Could you help me out?

Comment: Assume worst case and allocate enough memory to copy the whole array? Or is that not a suitable approach? Do you have a good approximation as to the size of the original array?

Comment: You can use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Make something like c++ vector. [How to replicate vector in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4694431/2549281)

Comment: By the way, is it possible to use dynamic memory allocation in CUDA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you have a speed-memory trade-off when it comes to performance.

In your two-loop version you are sacrificing speed for memory, while in the single-loop version you are sacrificing memory for speed.

You could try something like dynamically allocating the space every so many elements. For example, you allocate 5 elements worth of space, and when it's full you allocate an additional 5 elements, and so on. Unfortunately allocating space dynamically can take a significant portion of time.

I don't know of any other method than what you have described, though there may be something out there. In C++, for example, you could use a vector, which automatically resizes itself to accept new values in a method similar to what I've described.

Comment: "[…] though there may be something out there. In C++ […]" That would be [std::copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) from the `<algorithm>` header in c++11

Answer (score 2):

dynamically allocate memory for a `int`.
everytime you get a element satisfying the condition and add the element to a dynamically allocated array of integer.
use `realloc()` to increase the size of the `int` array pointed by some pointer and add the new element to that array.
use counter to know the number of elements in array.

Comment: shouldn't you use vector instead?

Comment: @Vladp Note the tag, this is `c`.

Comment: sorry, but still, allocating each single element is a waste, use vector approach and allocate more each time (1,2,4,8,...) this is much cheaper that way.