# C struct instance overwrites previous instance

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, memcpy

I'm new to C, so the answer might be obvious but I just can't get my head around it.

I'm trying to create [C++ vector kind of structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694401/how-to-replicate-vector-in-c). I use Windows EnumWindows function to loop through all the windows. In the callback function I create new instance of windowHandle -structure for each window. For some reason however it doesn't seem to create new instance but rather just overwrites the old one. Or maybe it creates new instance, but when I give value to attribute windowHandle->title, it applies that change to every instance of windowHandle?

Callback function:

```
BOOL CALLBACK delegate(HWND wnd, LPARAM param){
if (filter(wnd)){ //<- just to make sure it's kind of window that we want.
            char windowName[256] = {};
            GetWindowText(wnd, windowName, sizeof(windowName));
            windowHandle *handle = malloc(sizeof(windowHandle)); //<- create new instance of windowHandle for each window
            handle->hWND = wnd;
            handle->title = windowName;
            insert((windowArray*) param, handle); //<- insert each windowHandle in our 'vector'
        }
// but return true here so that we iterate all windows
return TRUE;
}
```

Call to EnumWindows function:

```
windowArray* array = array_init(20);
EnumWindows(&delegate, (LPARAM) array); //<- not quite sure what that '&'-sign does?
```

Structures:

```
typedef struct windowHandle{
    HWND hWND;
    char* title;
} windowHandle;

typedef struct windowArray{
    int count;
    int capacity;
    int objectSize;
    windowHandle* windows;
} windowArray;
```

And lastly insert:

```
int insert(windowArray* array, void* handle){
    int index = (array->count * array->objectSize);
    if(index > 0){
        printf("\n%s %s\n", "first element's title is: ", array->windows->title); //<- prints to see if new handle overwrite the previous ones
    }
    printf("%s %s %s %p %s %d\n", "Inserted element ", ((windowHandle*)handle)->title, " with pointer ", handle, " on index ", index);
    fflush(stdout); //<- prints info about first & current window
    memcpy(array->windows + (index), (windowHandle*)handle, array->objectSize);
    array->count++;
}
```

Output during insert calls:

```
Inserted element  joo - Java - nativeWindowCapture/src/NativeWindowHookImp.c - Eclipse SDK  with pointer  0000000000FB1B90  on index  0

first element's title is:  Komentokehote
Inserted element  Komentokehote  with pointer  0000000000FB1BB0  on index  16

first element's title is:  C struct instance overwrites previous instance - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
Inserted element  C struct instance overwrites previous instance - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox  with pointer  0000000000FB1BD0  on index  32

first element's title is:  JNI compiler kutsu – Muistio
Inserted element  JNI compiler kutsu – Muistio  with pointer  0000000000FB1BF0  on index  48

first element's title is:  Skype™?
Inserted element  Skype™? with pointer  0000000000FB1C10  on index  64

first element's title is:  eclipse
Inserted element  eclipse  with pointer  0000000000FB1C30  on index  80

first element's title is:  src
Inserted element  src  with pointer  0000000000FBCCE0  on index  96
all added
```

and then if I print the full content of windowArray->windows, I get the following results:

```
Getting value  src , at index  0  and pointer  0000000000FBBB80
Getting value  src , at index  16  and pointer  0000000000FBBC80
Getting value  src , at index  32  and pointer  0000000000FBBD80
Getting value  src , at index  48  and pointer  0000000000FBBE80
Getting value  src , at index  64  and pointer  0000000000FBBF80
Getting value  src , at index  80  and pointer  0000000000FBC080
Getting value  src , at index  96  and pointer  0000000000FBC180
```

P.S. I would also like to know why windowArray's `windows`-attribute's pointers are different from those of `*handle`-objects created in delegate? That doesn't seem to be very efficient memorywise?

Answer (score 4):

You set `handle->title` to point to `windowName`. But as soon as you exit this scope, `windowName` will cease to exist. So your structure contains a pointer to an array that no longer exists.

```
        char windowName[256] = {};
        GetWindowText(wnd, windowName, sizeof(windowName));
        windowHandle *handle = malloc(sizeof(windowHandle)); //<- create new instance of windowHandle for each window
        handle->hWND = wnd;
        handle->title = windowName;
    }
    // when we get here, windowName ceases to exist
    // so why did we store a pointer to it?
```

After you exit the scope, it is an error to follow the `title` pointer, since it no longer points to any object that is still alive. Perhaps change `title` from `char *` to `char[256]`.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Thank you! Saved the day.